# List<List<T>> property output to display in a TextBlock from the use of a ComboBoxItem

Tags: c#

I created List allPackages. The list is actually a list of lists of packages. I need to be able to click an item within the main application's ComboBox to select a state from the combo box list. After selecting the state, if there is a list of packages within the List allPackages that contains packages I need the Id field from each Package in the list to be displayed in a text block or some other type of tool within the UI. When I have tried I have been unsuccessful in having the accessed data field displayed to any kind of output within the UI.

I am looking into what is happening, but am pretty much stuck at this point. It is like the current running thread will not allow me to print the data. Of course this has to be because there is no method defined for an event of some type that handles when an item is selected from the ComboBox. The ComboBox I am referring to is the PkgsByStateCmbo. I'm almost certain this is the case. 
 From the posted code you will see that each Package object has an address, Id, state, zip, and a city. After clicking a button within the UI and completing the fields and validating the input the package can be added to a list of packages that is based upon the state field of the package to be added. This gives me lists based upon state. Looking now I sure that I maybe should have have used Linq statements in the code instead of nesting the lists, but I would still be in the current situation only with 1 list.

```
/** Package Class */
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CSC470_Lab6
{
    class Package
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set;}
        public string state { get; set; }
        public int zip { get; set; }
        public string city { get; set; }
    }
}
```

/** Controller Class */

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections;

namespace CSC470_Lab6
{
    class Controller
    {

        public List<List<Package>> allPackages = new List<List<Package>>();
        public string alI = "0";
        public string flI = "1";
        public string gaI = "2";
        public string kyI = "3";
        public string miI = "4";
        public string ncI = "5";
        public string scI = "6";
        public string tnI = "7";
        public string wvI = "8";
        public string vaI = "9";
        public int currentPkgCount = 0;
        public int initId = 10000;


        /**
         * Alabama, Florida, Georgia, Kentucky, Mississippi, North Carolina, South Carolina, Tennessee, West Virginia or Virginia.
         * */
        public List<Package> al = new List<Package>();
        public List<Package> fl = new List<Package>();
        public List<Package> ga = new List<Package>();
        public List<Package> ky = new List<Package>();
        public List<Package> mi = new List<Package>();
        public List<Package> nc = new List<Package>();
        public List<Package> sc = new List<Package>();
        public List<Package> tn = new List<Package>();
        public List<Package> wv = new List<Package>();
        public List<Package> va = new List<Package>();

        public void initMasterList()
        {
            allPackages.Add(al);
            allPackages.Add(fl);
            allPackages.Add(ga);
            allPackages.Add(ky);
            allPackages.Add(mi);
            allPackages.Add(nc);
            allPackages.Add(sc);
            allPackages.Add(tn);
            allPackages.Add(wv);
            allPackages.Add(va);

        }

        public Boolean masterListHasContent()
        {
            Boolean result = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < allPackages.Count; i++)
            {
                List<Package> temp = allPackages[i];
                if (temp[i] != null)
                { 
                    result = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return result;

        }

        public string[] getIds(List<Package> list)
        {
            string[] ids = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                ids[i] = list[i].Id;
            }
            return ids;
        }

        public List<Package> getStateList(int state)
        {

            return allPackages[state];
        }

        public void setInitId(){

            initId++;
        }

        public int getInitId()
        {
            return initId;
        }


    }
}
```

/** MainWindow.xam.cs */

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace CSC470_Lab6
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        string[] states = new string[] { "AL", "FL", "GA", "KY", "MI", "NC", "SC", "TN", "WV", "VA" };
        Package theCurrentPackage;
        Controller controller = new Controller();
        public int zipcode;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            controller.initMasterList();



        }
        private void PkgsByStateCmbo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (PkgsByStateCmbo.SelectedIndex >= 0)
            {
                int index = PkgsByStateCmbo.SelectedIndex;
                List<Package> list = controller.getStateList(index);

                foreach (Package pkg in list)
                {
                    ByStateBlk.Text = pkg.Id + "\n";
                }

            }
        }

        private void ScanBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            theCurrentPackage = new Package();
            PkgIdBlk.IsEnabled = true;
            controller.setInitId();
            controller.getInitId();
            PkgIdBlk.Text = controller.getInitId().ToString();
            theCurrentPackage.Id = controller.getInitId().ToString();
            setPackageAddress();
            setCity();
            setState();
            setZip();
            AddBtn.IsEnabled = true;
            ErrorViewer.IsEnabled = true;
            ScanBtn.IsEnabled = false;
        }
        public int getZip()
        {
            zipcode = int.Parse(ZipTxt.Text);
            return zipcode;
        }
        public void setZip()
        {
            ZipTxt.Text = "";
            ZipTxt.IsEnabled = true;
        }
        public string getState()
        {
            int index;
            index = StateCmbo.SelectedIndex - 1;
            if (index >= 0)
                return states[index];
            else
                return "NVS";
        }
        public void setState()
        {

            StateCmbo.IsEnabled = true;
        }
        public void setCity()
        {
            CityTxt.Text = "";
            CityTxt.IsEnabled = true;
        }
        public string getCity()
        {
            return CityTxt.Text;
        }
        public void setPackageAddress()
        {
            AddressTxt.Text = "";
            AddressTxt.IsEnabled = true;

        }
        public string getPackageAddress()
        {
            return AddressTxt.Text;

        }


        private void AddBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ScanBtn.IsEnabled = false;

            bool addr = checkAddress();
            bool cty = checkCity();
            bool ckst = checkState();
            bool chdz = checkZip();
            if((addr == true)&&(cty == true)&&(ckst == true)&&(chdz == true))

            {
                theCurrentPackage.address = getPackageAddress();
                theCurrentPackage.city = getCity();
                theCurrentPackage.zip = getZip();
                theCurrentPackage.state = getState();
                ErrorViewer.Content = "Package added";
                int index = StateCmbo.SelectedIndex - 1;
                controller.allPackages[index].Add(theCurrentPackage);
                theCurrentPackage = null;
                AddressTxt.Text = "";
                PkgIdBlk.Text = "";
                CityTxt.Text = "";
                ZipTxt.Text = "";
                ScanBtn.IsEnabled = true;
                StateCmbo.SelectedIndex = -1;
                StateCmbo.IsEnabled = false;
                PkgsByStateCmbo.IsEnabled = true;


            }
           else
            {

                ErrorViewer.Content = "Package add unsuccessful. Please check for errors and try again";
                PkgIdBlk.Text = "";
                AddressTxt.Text = "";
                CityTxt.Text = "";
                StateCmbo.SelectedIndex = -1;
                ZipTxt.Text = "";
                AddBtn.IsEnabled = false;
                ScanBtn.IsEnabled = true;
                theCurrentPackage = null;
            }

        }

        public bool checkState()
        {
            bool result = false;
            if (getState() != "NVS")
            {
                result = true;
            }
            return result;
        }

        public bool checkAddress()
        {
            bool result = false;
            string str = getPackageAddress();
            if (str != null)
                result = true;
            return result;
        }

        public bool checkCity()
        {
            bool result = false;
            string str = getCity();
            if (str != null)
                result = true;
            return result;
        }

        public bool checkZip()
        {
            bool result = false;

            char[] zip = zipcode.ToString().ToCharArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < zip.Length; i++)
            {
                int val = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(zip[i]);

                if ((val.Equals(0)) || (val.Equals(1)) || (val.Equals(2)) || (val.Equals(3)) || (val.Equals(4))|| (val.Equals(5)) || (val.Equals(6))|| (val.Equals(7))|| (val.Equals(8)) || (val.Equals(9)))
                {

                    result = true;
                    //return result;
                }
                else
                {
                    result = false;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }





    }           
}

<Window x:Class="CSC470_Lab6.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid IsEnabled="True">


        <Button x:Name="NextBtn" Content="Next &gt;" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="71" Margin="315,235,0,0" IsEnabled="False"/>
        <Button x:Name="ExitBtn" Content="Exit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="44" Margin="266,235,0,0"/>
        <Button x:Name="RemoveBtn" Content="Remove" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="60" Margin="201,235,0,0" IsEnabled="False"/>
        <Button x:Name="AddBtn" Content="Add" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="48" Margin="148,234,0,0" IsEnabled="False" Click="AddBtn_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="ScanBtn" Content="Scan New" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="72" Margin="71,234,0,0" Click="ScanBtn_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="BackBtn" Content="&lt; Back" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,234,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="56" IsEnabled="False"/>
        <Grid x:Name="InnerGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="135" Margin="10,94,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="376">
            <Label x:Name="PackageIdLbl" Content="Package ID:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,14,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsEnabled="False"/>
            <Label x:Name="AddressLbl" Content="Address" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,52,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsEnabled="False"/>
            <Label x:Name="CityLbl" Content="City" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,93,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsEnabled="False"/>
            <Label x:Name="StateLbl" Content="State" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="207,95,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsEnabled="False"/>
            <Label x:Name="ZipLbl" Content="Zip" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="286,95,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsEnabled="False"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="CityTxt" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="87,99,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="City_Text" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsEnabled="False"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="ZipTxt" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="318,97,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="00000" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="48" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsEnabled="False"/>
            <ComboBox x:Name="StateCmbo" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="244,98,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42" RenderTransformOrigin="1.614,0.47" IsEnabled="False">
                <ComboBoxItem x:Name="noSelection" Content=""/>
                <ComboBoxItem x:Name="al" Content="AL"/>
                <ComboBoxItem x:Name="fl" Content="FL"/>
                <ComboBoxItem x:Name="ga" Content="GA"/>
                <ComboBoxItem x:Name="ky" Content="KY"/>
                <ComboBoxItem x:Name="mi" Content="MI"/>
                <ComboBoxItem x:Name="nc" Content="NC"/>
                <ComboBoxItem x:Name="sc" Content="SC"/>
                <ComboBoxItem x:Name="tn" Content="TN"/>
                <ComboBoxItem x:Name="wv" Content="WV"/>
                <ComboBoxItem x:Name="va" Content="VA"/>
            </ComboBox>
            <TextBlock x:Name="PkgIdBlk" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="87,19,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="279" />
            <TextBox x:Name="AddressTxt" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="87,53,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Address_Text" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="279" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsEnabled="False"/>
        </Grid>
        <GroupBox x:Name="PkgInfoGrp" Header="Package Information&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,95,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="140" Width="376" IsEnabled="True"/>
        <Label x:Name="ArrivedAtLbl" Content="Arrived At:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,63,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="69" IsEnabled="False"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="ArrivedAtTxtBlk" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="99,68,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="130" />
        <GroupBox x:Name="PkgsByStateGrp" Header="Packages by state" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="391,94,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="160" Width="117" IsEnabled="True">
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="0,38,-3,-0.4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="107">
                <TextBlock x:Name="ByStateBlk" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="90" Width="107" Text="{Binding PkgsByStateCmbo, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            </Grid>
        </GroupBox>
        <ComboBox x:Name="PkgsByStateCmbo" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="420,122,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="65" IsReadOnly="True" Height="23" IsEnabled="True" SelectedItem="{Binding allPackages[SelectedIndex].List.state, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <ComboBoxItem Content=""/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="AL"/> 
            <ComboBoxItem Content="FL"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="GA"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="KY"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="MI"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="NC"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="SC"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="TN"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="WV"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="VA"/>
        </ComboBox>
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="ErrorViewer" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="47" Margin="10,264,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="498"/>


    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Are you saying you want one package per line in the TextBlock?

Comment: No, just the packageId. So if I click the AL from the ComboBox I want all packages from the AL list to have their packageId listed in the TextBlock

Comment: @JNicholas76  may be change = to += ?   ByStateBlk.Text += pkg.Id + "\n";

Comment: I've tried, it hasn't worked. It is odd. It has to have something to do with the current thread of the application. I don't know how to control the event of selecting an item from the ComboBox or something. If I code is a String to be output to the desired TextBlock in the main method to execute at runtime it will accept it. But, that's not any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corrected Code is as follows, I also commented that I changed the original TextBlock to an ListBox which was part of the solution. I also had to add an inner loop to the PkgsByStateCombo_SelectionChanged method.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace CSC470_Lab6
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        int startingIndex = 0;
        string[] states = new string[] { "AL", "FL", "GA", "KY", "MI", "NC", "SC", "TN", "WV", "VA" };
        Package theCurrentPackage;
        Controller controller = new Controller();
        List<Package> newList = new List<Package>();
        public int zipcode;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            PkgsByStateCmbo.ItemsSource = states;
            controller.initMasterList();
            for (int i = 0; i < controller.allPackages.Count; i++)
            {
                List<Package> lst = controller.allPackages[i];
                lst.Clear();
            }



        }


        private void ScanBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ArrivedAtTxtBlk.IsEnabled = true;
            theCurrentPackage = new Package();
            PkgIdBlk.IsEnabled = true;
            controller.setInitId();
            controller.getInitId();
            PkgIdBlk.Text = controller.getInitId().ToString();
            theCurrentPackage.Id = controller.getInitId().ToString();
            setPackageAddress();
            setCity();
            setState();
            setZip();
            AddBtn.IsEnabled = true;
            ErrorViewer.IsEnabled = true;
            ScanBtn.IsEnabled = false;
            DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
            ArrivedAtTxtBlk.Text = time.ToString();
        }
        public int getZip()
        {
            zipcode = int.Parse(ZipTxt.Text);
            return zipcode;
        }
        public void setZip()
        {
            ZipTxt.Text = "";
            ZipTxt.IsEnabled = true;
        }
        public string getState()
        {
            int index;
            index = StateCmbo.SelectedIndex - 1;
            if (index >= 0)
                return states[index];
            else
                return "NVS";
        }
        public void setState()
        {

            StateCmbo.IsEnabled = true;
        }
        public void setCity()
        {
            CityTxt.Text = "";
            CityTxt.IsEnabled = true;
        }
        public string getCity()
        {
            return CityTxt.Text;
        }
        public void setPackageAddress()
        {
            AddressTxt.Text = "";
            AddressTxt.IsEnabled = true;

        }
        public string getPackageAddress()
        {
            return AddressTxt.Text;

        }


        private void AddBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ScanBtn.IsEnabled = false;

            bool addr = checkAddress();
            bool cty = checkCity();
            bool ckst = checkState();
            bool chdz = checkZip();
            if((addr == true)&&(cty == true)&&(ckst == true)&&(chdz == true))

            {
                theCurrentPackage.address = getPackageAddress();
                theCurrentPackage.city = getCity();
                theCurrentPackage.zip = getZip();
                theCurrentPackage.state = getState();
                ErrorViewer.Content = "Package added";
                int index = StateCmbo.SelectedIndex - 1;
                controller.allPackages[index].Add(theCurrentPackage);
                //newList.Add(theCurrentPackage);
                //theCurrentPackage = null;
                AddressTxt.Text = "";
                PkgIdBlk.Text = "";
                CityTxt.Text = "";
                ZipTxt.Text = "";
                ScanBtn.IsEnabled = true;
                StateCmbo.SelectedIndex = -1;
                StateCmbo.IsEnabled = false;
                PkgsByStateCmbo.IsEnabled = true;
                NextBtn.IsEnabled = true;
                BackBtn.IsEnabled = true;

            }
           else
            {

                ErrorViewer.Content = "Package add unsuccessful. Please check for errors and try again";
                PkgIdBlk.Text = "";
                AddressTxt.Text = "";
                CityTxt.Text = "";
                StateCmbo.SelectedIndex = -1;
                ZipTxt.Text = "";
                AddBtn.IsEnabled = false;
                ScanBtn.IsEnabled = true;
                theCurrentPackage = null;

            }

        }

        public bool checkState()
        {
            bool result = false;
            if (getState() != "NVS")
            {
                result = true;
            }
            return result;
        }

        public bool checkAddress()
        {
            bool result = false;
            string str = getPackageAddress();
            if (str != null)
                result = true;
            return result;
        }

        public bool checkCity()
        {
            bool result = false;
            string str = getCity();
            if (str != null)
                result = true;
            return result;
        }

        public bool checkZip()
        {
            bool result = false;

            char[] zip = zipcode.ToString().ToCharArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < zip.Length; i++)
            {
                int val = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(zip[i]);

                if ((val.Equals(0)) || (val.Equals(1)) || (val.Equals(2)) || (val.Equals(3)) || (val.Equals(4))|| (val.Equals(5)) || (val.Equals(6))|| (val.Equals(7))|| (val.Equals(8)) || (val.Equals(9)))
                {

                    result = true;
                    //return result;
                }
                else
                {
                    result = false;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }



        private void NextBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (startingIndex < newList.Count)
            {
                startingIndex++;
                AddressTxt.Text = newList[startingIndex].address;
                CityTxt.Text = newList[startingIndex].city;
                //string str = newList[startingIndex].state;
                //for (int i = 0; i < states.Length; i++)
                //{
                //    if (states[i] == str)
                //    {
                //        StateCmbo.SelectedIndex = i;
                //    }
                //}
                ZipTxt.Text = newList[startingIndex].zip.ToString();
            }
            else if(startingIndex >= newList.Count)
            {
                AddressTxt.Text = newList.Last().address;
                CityTxt.Text = newList.Last().city;
                string str = newList.Last().state;
                for (int i = 0; i < states.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (states[i] == str)
                    {
                        StateCmbo.SelectedIndex = i + 1;
                    }
                }
                ZipTxt.Text = newList.Last().zip.ToString();
            }


        }

        private void PkgsByStateCmbo_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ByStateListBox.Items.Clear();
            if (PkgsByStateCmbo.SelectedIndex >= 0)
            {
                int selectionI = PkgsByStateCmbo.SelectedIndex;
                newList = controller.allPackages[selectionI];
                foreach (Package p in newList)
                {
                    if (p.state == PkgsByStateCmbo.SelectedItem)
                    {
                        ByStateListBox.Items.Add(p.Id.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }

        } 



    }           
}
```

The combination of the MainWindow constructor and the selection changed method changes were what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Let me say in advance, I have no example what the Package class looks like, so it is based on assumptions. Whereas I assume that they have a Name and ID property. Besides that, I also assume that they have unique names and id's. That is why I use FirstOrDefault().

I would do the following:

```
private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e){
    //Get the selected combobox item
    ComboBoxItem selectedItem = (String)((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem;

    //Get the string out of the combobox item
    String state = selectedItem.Content;

    //Get the packageId from the allpackages list
    Int64 packageId = (allPackages.Where(p => p.package.state.equals(state)).FirstOrDefault()).Id;

    //Put the number in the textbox
    PkgIdBlk.Text = packageId.ToString();
}
```

@Edit 13:30 22-07-2015

I read that there is a list of list of packages. (It would help to have the package class.) In that case if you want a list of id's, the following would apply:

```
private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e){
    //Get the selected combobox item
    ComboBoxItem selectedItem = (String)((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem;

    //Get the string out of the combobox item
    String state = selectedItem.Content;

    //Get the list of packages from the allpackages list where the name applies
    List<Package> packages = allPackages.Where(p => p.package.state.equals(state)).ToList();

    //create a string to fill with id's
    String idList = "";

    //Loop to the prior selected list to fill the string with id's
    foreach(Package p in packages){
        idList += p.ID + ", ";
    }

    //Put the numberlist in the textbox
    PkgIdBlk.Text = idList;
}
```

(You can also work with the StringBuilder class. But for simplicity I used a String.)

@edit 22:34 23-07-2015
Edited the answer for the package class which is now available. (Replaced name by state)

The reason why the textbox is empty can have multiple reasons, here are three;

1. The String state is empty, for some reason not filled right with the SelectedItem.Content. Which causes the Linq query to come up with no results.
2. The Linq (where) query has no results. Which means the foreach loop doesn't add anything to the string idList? (Keep in mind the equals statement is case sensitive.)
3. Set the idList string to the wrong textbox?

@edit 22:43 23-07-2015
I see one problem, this:

```
    ComboBoxItem selectedItem = (String)((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem;
```

Should be this:

```
    ComboBoxItem selectedItem = (ComboBoxItem)((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will study the latter case that you have posted here because it is the case. From what It looks like, I imagine it may be what I'm looking for.  I will also post the Package class as well. Thanks for the post

Comment: I tried and it's not sending the idList String to any TextBlock

Comment: Is the string empty? You can check that with debugging.

Comment: The string is not empty, it's just accessing some records from a list and getting their PackageId number ( a field of each list item). I know it's not empty because if there are no Packages, the ComboBox is disabled. I will be working on another project for a few days and will come back to this then. If anyone has any ideas, please post and I will get back in a day or two.

Comment: Took some time but I finally figured out what was going on. Firstly, I set the ComboBox.ItemsSource property within the following
     public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            PkgsByStateCmbo.ItemsSource = states;
            controller.initMasterList();
            for (int i = 0; i < controller.allPackages.Count; i++)
            {
                List<Package> lst = controller.allPackages[i];
                lst.Clear();
            }
       }
I'll update OP with corrected code. Thanks anyone who tried to help. I'm unfamiliar with VS and WPF